# how can i check ajax request before controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, request, laravel-7

i have a question about ajax requests. is there a solution to define a rout just for ajax requests before controller??
i always use a Condition like this in the related method:

```
    public function ajaxRequest(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

thanks for your help

Comment: what do you want to do if the request is ajax? you can do this in the middleware so that every request passes through the check. You write it once in the middleware and apply the middleware on desired routes.

Answer (score 1):

A route cannot be defined only for ajax requests without some type of key.

But ajax requests can be defined **before controller** without a controller at *routes/web.php*

```
Route::get('/crud', function(){
   //get
   return \App\Models\Products::all();
});

Route::post('/crud', function(){
   //set   
   return \App\Models\Products::update([
      'product_name' => (new \Illuminate\Http\Request)['name_product']
   ]);
});

...
```